# Node.js unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, port

I have written a simple code and save it in file try.js  .

```
var http = require('http');
var makeRequest = function(message) {
  var options = {
    host: 'localhost', port: 8080, path: '/', method: 'POST'
  }
  var request = http.request(options, function(response){
    response.on('data', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

  request.write(message);
  request.end();
}
makeRequest("Here's looking at you, kid.");
```

When I run it through terminal it give an error

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event,
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:875:19)error' event
```

Comment: i have tried to change the port but it is still not working

Answer (score 46):

For me, the problem was another instance was running. Search for other node instance running and kill it. It should resume properly after.

Comment: This answer actually helped me out for one case of "Unhandled 'error' event".

Comment: This also happened to me on Windows, closed all node command prompts, reopened them and it started working again. Go figure.

Comment: I had another instance running. Sure enough I killed it and the error went away.

Comment: i had too another instance running..Thank you

Answer (score 12):

This is happening because nothing is listening on localhost:8080. Here are the examples how to handle request errors [How to catch http client request exceptions in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328540/how-to-catch-http-client-request-exceptions-in-node-js)

Answer (score 7):

Another server is running on same port 8080, so you need to kill and start your instance.

**find running instance**

```
$ netstat -nlp | grep 8080

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::8881                 :::*                    LISTEN      28207/node
```

**kill existing server instance using pid**

```
$ kill -9 28207
```

**start instance**

```
$ node server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

change port number. Because your port is already is running.

port number like  : 8000,8001,3000,3001,8080 ....

```
 app.listen(3030,()=>{})
```

(or)
Kill your port number. If you are using Ubuntu OS to follow this steps.

1. To Find PID or TCP using terminal using this command:
   **sudo netstat -ap | grep :"port number"**
2. To Kill the process using this command:
   **kill -9 "process_id or tcp_id"**
3. To Run your NodeJs

Answer (score 0):

Another server is running on the same port 8080 so change the port in this code or kill the port 8080 and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

A different process is already running in the same port. Either kill the running process or change the port number in the current code. Your issue will be fixed!