# Can build and run image locally. Cannot build and run image via Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

From my application's root directory, I can build an image and run it locally. When I use the image built via the kubernetes engine, it successfully builds, but the application errors.[image: image of error logs]

The logs above are from kubernete's dashboard, they show the error that occurs when trying to run the application.

I've also changed my local environment to the node/npm version to match the version noted in the logs and the app. The app runs with no issues locally.

I've only found one other user with a similar issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/142 so I'm pretty stumped as to what it could be, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Rather than being an image/cloud issue, could the initial "throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event" be related to another container running node.js that creates a conflict with your app as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331783/node-js-unhandled-error-event

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try to use this tool to see the images differences? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-diff
2. Did you try to deploy your local image to GKE to check it is actually working?

Also, you should probably try to catch the gulp error in order to understand better what's going wrong. https://medium.com/@boriscoder/catching-errors-on-gulp-js-4682eee2669f

Cheers,
Philmod