# ECONNREFUSED in Node http module

Tags: node.js, node-request

When a remote site is off-line I am getting this error in my consuming client (Node.js v0.12.0 with the `http` module):

```
 Uncaught exception: connect ECONNREFUSED
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:983:19)
```

The code I'm currently using looks like this:

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.on('socket', function (socket) {
        socket.setKeepAlive(true, 0);
        socket.setNoDelay(true);
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        log.debug('Success');
    }).on('error', function () {
        log.error('Response parsing failed');
    });
}).on('error', function () {
    log.error('HTTP request failed');
});

req.write(packet);
req.end();
```

The "error" event is never fired when the `ECONNREFUSED` occurs, I've tried using the "[clientError](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror)" event but this is not fired either.

How can I capture this error?

Comment: Are you using io.js?

Comment: No I'm not currently

Comment: have you tried to call req.end(); at the end of your code? The documentation stated hier: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback: "Note that in the example req.end() was called. With http.request() one must always call req.end() to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body."

Comment: @solick great question. I do actually have `req.end()` by I cut it out when condensing my example code for this question. I'll put it back.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328705/4478897

> **NOTE: This post is a bit old**

The next example is with the `http.createClient` but i think it could be the same

> Unfortunately, at the moment there's no way to catch these exceptions directly, since all the stuff happens asynchronously in the background.
>
> All you can do is to catch the uncaughtException's on your own:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Maybe that helps you!

More this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19793797/4478897

**UPDATE:**

did you tried to change `log.error()` to `console.error()` ???